# No module named items

Tags: python

I know its been asked million times. However, I still can't figure out my situation.If I create minimal example, my folder structure looks like that:

```
.
├── Project_L
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── First_sp.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

items.py :

```
import scrapy


class ProjectLItem(scrapy.Item):
     name = scrapy.Field()
```

And there's just one import line

```
from Project_L.items import ProjectLItem
```

I'm getting

```
'No module named Project_L.items'
```

Ok, I thought. That's my both right hands. I've downloaded Dimitrios Kouzis-Loukas "Learning Scrapy" book's samples from github. Spitting same error.

Comment: remove Project_L before items, keep it like from items import ProjectLItem...

Comment: What is doing the import? And what is the working directory/the contents of `sys.path`. You can't find `Project_L` if the parent directory isn't the working directory and doesn't appear in `sys.path`.

Comment: zenwraight: in that case err looks like : No module items; ShadowRangers: Import is importing items. If that what you were asking. sys.path looks like:  ['/home/python/Python/code/Project_L/Project_L/spiders', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pdbpp_path_hack', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']